# How to join two QGraphicsPixmapItem with a QLine?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have two `QGraphicsPixmapItem` added to my `QGraphicsScene`.

Now I want to add a `QLine` connecting both of this `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and should be able to move around with `QLine` stretching like graph.

I have looked into this [Elastic Nodes Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html), but it's too complicated for me.

based on this: [How to use itemChange from QGraphicsItem in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192607/how-to-use-itemchange-from-qgraphicsitem-in-qt/32198716#32198716), I was able to solve my problem except I am struggling to replace `QGraphicsEllipseItem` with `QGraphicsPixmapItem` because of rect argument, which is needed in another function for calculating position.

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QGraphicsScene>

#include <QGraphicsView>

#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

#include <QGraphicsLineItem>

class CustomElipse : public QGraphicsEllipseItem

{

public:

    CustomElipse (const QRectF& rect) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect) {

        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);

    }

    void addLine(QGraphicsLineItem *line, bool isPoint1) {

        this->line = line;

        isP1 = isPoint1;

    }

    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)

    {

        if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {

            // value is the new position.

            QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();

            moveLineToCenter(newPos);

        }

        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);

    }

    void moveLineToCenter(QPointF newPos) {

        // Converts the elipse position (top-left)

        // to its center position

        int xOffset = rect().x() + rect().width()/2;

        int yOffset = rect().y() + rect().height()/2;

        QPointF newCenterPos = QPointF(newPos.x() + xOffset, newPos.y() + yOffset);

        // Move the required point of the line to the center of the elipse

        QPointF p1 = isP1 ? newCenterPos : line->line().p1();

        QPointF p2 = isP1 ? line->line().p2() : newCenterPos;

        line->setLine(QLineF(p1, p2));

    }

private:

    QGraphicsLineItem *line;

    bool isP1;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;

    CustomElipse *elipse1 = new CustomElipse(QRectF(30, 30, 15, 25));

    scene.addItem(elipse1);

    CustomElipse *elipse2 = new CustomElipse(QRectF(70, 70, 25, 15));

    scene.addItem(elipse2);

    QGraphicsLineItem *line = scene.addLine(QLineF(40, 40, 80, 80));

    elipse1->addLine(line, true);

    elipse2->addLine(line, false);

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    view.show();

    return a.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt Documentation of [QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicspixmapitem.html):

> The QGraphicsPixmapItem class provides a pixmap item that you can add to a QGraphicsScene.

Here's an example with comments on the changes I made:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>
#include <QPixmap>

class CustomElipse : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    //Use a QPixmap instead of QRect
    CustomElipse (const QPixmap& pixmap) : QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap) 
    {
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
    }

    void addLine(QGraphicsLineItem *line, bool isPoint1) 
    {
        this->line = line;
        isP1 = isPoint1;
    }

    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
    {
        if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) 
        {
            // value is the new position.
            QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
            moveLineToCenter(newPos);
        }
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }
    
    void moveLineToCenter(QPointF newPos) 
    {
        // Converts the elipse position (top-left)
        // to its center position
        //use pixmap's rect to calculate the offset
        int xOffset = pixmap().rect().x() + pixmap().width()/2;
        int yOffset = pixmap().rect().y() + pixmap().height()/2;

        QPointF newCenterPos = QPointF(newPos.x() + xOffset, newPos.y() + yOffset);

        // Move the required point of the line to the center of the elipse
        QPointF p1 = isP1 ? newCenterPos : line->line().p1();
        QPointF p2 = isP1 ? line->line().p2() : newCenterPos;

        line->setLine(QLineF(p1, p2));
    }

private:
    QGraphicsLineItem *line;
    bool isP1;
};

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;

    //I used an image of a green circle to test it
    CustomElipse *elipse1 = new CustomElipse(QPixmap(":green.png"));
    scene.addItem(elipse1);

    CustomElipse *elipse2 = new CustomElipse(QPixmap(":green.png"));
    scene.addItem(elipse2);

    QGraphicsLineItem *line = scene.addLine(QLineF(40, 40, 80, 80));
    elipse1->addLine(line, true);
    elipse2->addLine(line, false);

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result]